# Making div overflow for draggable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

On a button click event I am able to generate draggable divs using jquery ui. I am able to drag the new created divs inside a container div `class=” middle-side”`. Right now the draggable div is fixed to stay inside the space set to the container.  I want to to give it more drag space but keep the initial height and width boundary for the the container. how can I the following: If I keep dragging the div all the way to the right to make the container div scroll. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bullseye2346/0wbnud4k/46/)

Jquery

```
var z = 1;
$('#button').click(function (e) {
    /** Make div draggable **/
    $('<div />', {
        class: 'draggable ui-widget-content',
        html: '<span class="close">[X]</span><span class="text">' + $('textarea').val() + '</span>',
        appendTo: '.middle-side',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent',
            start: function( event, ui ) {
                $(this).css('z-index', ++z);
            }
        }
    }).addClass('placement');
});
```

CSS

```
.middle-side {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px solid;
}
.draggable {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background:#FFFFDD;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.placement {
    border: 2px dashed #000;
}
```

HTML

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Enter Text Here!"></textarea>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Add Div with Text" />
<br/>
<div>
    <div class="middle-side empty"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @fernandopasik An example, if I keep dragging the div all the way to the right to make the container div scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the intended behavior:

http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/49/

I placed an intermediate bigger div and made your container scroll.

```
<div class="middle-side">
    <div class="droppable"></div>
</div>
```

Also everything is appended to the inside div and the position of the object absolute and relative to the inside div.

```
.middle-side {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px solid;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.droppable {
    width: 2000px;
    height: 2000px;
    position: relative;
}

.draggable {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background:#FFFFDD;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.placement {
    border: 2px dashed #000;
}
```